# Is Ackermann's Function Bijective?

Tags: ackermann-function

I have been trying to understand the more rigorous side of mathematics and especially functions, and I came across Ackermann's Function recently. I was wondering if A(x,y) is bijective *among the natural numbers* for any pair (x,y). If it isn't, is it injective or surjective? Any proofs would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Looking at this wikipedia page, it seems $A(0,y) = y+1$ for $y \in \mathbb{W}$ is bijective with $\mathbb{N}$. So $A(x,y)$ for general $(x,y)$ is surjective on $\mathbb{N}$. But since $A(x,y)$ maps to natural numbers for $x>0$ as well, $A(x,y)$ is not injective. So not bijective. I'm writing this as a comment since this is the first I'm reading of the function, so could very well be mistaken. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function

Comment: Following Tony's comment, it would be useful to state in the question whether you include $0$ in your "natural numbers"

Comment: Also state what you mean by "bijective" for a function of two variables.

Comment: 1. I am not including 0 because that can't be reached by A(x,y)
2. Tony is absolutely right (surjective ✅ injective ❌) and I should've realized that
3. For GEdgar, I would say that a function is "bijective" for two variables if it is surjective and A(a,b) = A(c,d) implies that (a,b) = (c,d).

Sorry for being a noob, I'm new here. Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function)'s table of values: $A(1,3)=5=A(2,1)$.

That disproves injectivity.

For surjectivity just convince yourself that $1$ can't be reached ($2$ can't be either). (As $A(1,n)=n+2$ the function is surjective onto $\mathbb N\setminus\{1,2\}$).